# Chaining of pipes, forks and execs, bash like behaviour in C

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork, exec

I am trying to emulate this bash command: `ls -la | cut -c 20-30 | grep -v echelinho` in C using forks, pipes and execs, here's the code I have so far that displays nothing after execution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc , char**argv){

    int **pipes;
    int i;
    int pid1, pid2, pid3;

    pipes = malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        pipes[i] = malloc (2*sizeof(int));
        pipe(pipes[i]);
    }

    pid1=fork();
    if(!pid1){
        close(pipes[0][0]);
        dup2(pipes[0][1],1);
        execlp("ls","ls","-la",NULL);
    }

    pid2=fork();
    if(!pid2){
        waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
        close(pipes[0][1]);
        close(pipes[1][0]);
        dup2(pipes[0][0],0);
        dup2(pipes[1][1],1);
        execlp("cut","cut","-c", "20-30", NULL);
    }

    pid3=fork();
    if(!pid3){
        waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
        close(pipes[1][1]);
        dup2(pipes[1][0],0);
        execlp("grep","grep","-v", "echelinho", NULL);
    }
}
```

Could someone point out my mistakes or get this piece of code working? I understand I'm not error handling and that that's not a good habit to feed, but I'm only doing this to better understand the concepts and not for pratical/real world applications.

Comment: Error checking (and logging) would no doubt aid you in discovering your problem(s).

Comment: You can simply delete your own question if you want to, simply click "delete" below the question (you might need to delete your self-answer first). All self-vandalism will get you is a temporary suspension.

Comment: Please don't vandlaize your posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the mistakes on my own.

Two of the most impactful mistakes were :

- Not closing some part of the pipes on every process envolved;
- Waiting for the child processes to end were on the wrong place of the code.

Here's the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc , char**argv){

    int fdfst[2];
    int fdsnd[2];

    pipe(fdfst);
    pipe(fdsnd);

    switch(fork()){
        case -1: 
            perror("Error on fork.");
        case 0:
            close(fdfst[0]);
            close(fdsnd[0]);
            close(fdsnd[1]);
            dup2(fdfst[1],1);
            close(fdfst[1]);
            execlp("ls","ls","-la",NULL);
    }

    switch(fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("Error on fork.");
        case 0:
            close(fdfst[1]);
            close(fdsnd[0]);
            dup2(fdfst[0],0);
            close(fdfst[0]);
            dup2(fdsnd[1],1);
            close(fdsnd[1]);
            execlp("cut","cut","-c", "20-30", NULL);
    }

    switch(fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("Error on fork.");
        case 0:
            close(fdfst[0]);
            close(fdfst[1]);
            close(fdsnd[1]);
            dup2(fdsnd[0],0);
            close(fdsnd[0]);
            execlp("grep","grep","-v", "echelinho", NULL);
    }

    close(fdfst[0]);
    close(fdfst[1]);
    close(fdsnd[0]);
    close(fdsnd[1]);

    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```